# Trigger not firing even though passes Test Class

Tags: apex, trigger

Afternoon all,

Thanks to some helpful advice on here I have got my trigger passing its test class, only problem now is that i just isn't working. I've tried using a dummy record with the correct entry criteria but I get nothing. My guess is I have an issue with the wrapping syntax but I don't know for sure. Any ideas?

Trigger

```
trigger CreateContractTrigger2YearDealTerm on Contract (after insert, after update) {
    List <Opportunity> listOppor = new list <Opportunity>();
    for (Contract con : Trigger.new) {
{

   if(con.RPI__c == 'Yes' && con.ContractTerm == 24 && con.Status == 'Activated' && con.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c == FALSE && con.RPI_Trigger_Frequency__c == 'Annually')
       {
            Opportunity oppNew = new Opportunity ();
          oppNew.Type = 'Incremental Contract Trigger';

          oppNew.StageName = '10% - Gathering Info/Preparing Solution';
          oppNew.Name = con.Account +' - ' + con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c + ' - ' + oppNew.Type;
           oppNew.Service_Live_Date__c = con.StartDate.addYears(1);
           oppNew.CloseDate = con.StartDate.addDays(364);
           oppNew.Highlevel_Product_Type__c = con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c;
           oppNew.Trigger_Type__c = 'Retail Price Index';
           oppNew.Contract_Trigger_Activity_Stage__c = 'Not Yet Started';           
           oppNew.Probability = .10;

          listOppor.add(oppNew);

       }


   if(con.PPUP_Mechanism__c == 'Yes' && con.ContractTerm == 24 && con.Status == 'Activated' && con.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c == FALSE && con.PPUP_Trigger_Frequency__c == 'Annually')
       {
            Opportunity oppNew = new Opportunity ();
          oppNew.Type = 'Incremental Contract Trigger';

          oppNew.StageName = '10% - Gathering Info/Preparing Solution';
          oppNew.Name = con.Account +' - ' + con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c + ' - ' + oppNew.Type;
           oppNew.Service_Live_Date__c = con.StartDate.addYears(1);
           oppNew.CloseDate = con.StartDate.addDays(364);
           oppNew.Highlevel_Product_Type__c = con.Highlevel_Product_Type__c;
           oppNew.Trigger_Type__c = 'Price Per Usage Point';
           oppNew.Contract_Trigger_Activity_Stage__c = 'Not Yet Started';
           oppNew.Probability = .10;


          listOppor.add(oppNew);

       }
    if(listOppor.size() > 0)
     insert listOppor;    
}
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest

public class TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months
{
Static testMethod void TestCreateOppsOnContracts24Months(){
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert testAccount;

    Contract c = new Contract();
    c.AccountID = testAccount.Id;
    c.Status = 'Draft';
    c.Contract_Sponsor__c = 'Craig Coates';
    c.StartDate = date.today();
    c.Contract_Type__c = 'IAR';
    c.ContractTerm = 24;
    c.Business_Division__c = 'Commercial Team';
    c.EndDate = c.StartDate.addYears(2);
    c.Pricing_Signed_off_by__c = 'Rate Card';
    c.Margin__c = 0.1;
    c.RPI__c = 'Yes';
    c.RPI_Description__c = 'Test RPI Description';
    c.RPI_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
    c.PPUP_Mechanism__c = 'Yes';
    c.PPUP_Mechanism_Description__c = 'Test PPUP Description';
    c.PPUP_Trigger_Frequency__c = 'Annually';
    c.Triggers_Auto_Fired__c = FALSE;
    insert c;

    c.Status = 'Activated';
    update c;

    }
}
```

Comment: did you check it is active? Did you check the debug log are you getting any error

Comment: can you post your test class as well?

Comment: Defiitely active, no debug log. Added Test Class to.

Comment: Are you certain the trigger is not firing versus the if criteria in the trigger not evaluating to true?  I would start by adding system.debug() messages in the trigger that output to debug the values in your IF criteria.

Comment: Try to find out by writing few Debug's in your code - so you can understand it in better way. Check if you are failing to Pass any Validation Rule (Can see this in your Debug logs too)

Comment: Why do you have { in you 4th line?

Comment: As an aside, the fact that your test "Passes" without actually firing the trigger is indicative of an ineffective test class. You really have no test class there at all as you are not testing anything. You are just covering line.

Comment: And what to you mean "Get nothing". According to your code you are not trying to get anything. At a minimum query for opportunities and assert the size is > 1. If that passes then your trigger is firing. Still do not know what you mean by "I get nothing"

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the creation of two opportunities upon activation of a contract. That's not hapenning, hence 'get nothing'

Comment: @CaptainHaZ - How could you know that it is not happening, your test is not checking to see if it did nor not.

Comment: @Eric I actually activated a contract in my sandbox and expected the opportunities to be created bu they weren't.

Comment: @CaptainHaZ - Huh, this is about test methods, not what happens when you do the UI. This question needs to be closed....

Comment: I actually asked the question as to why my triggers weren't firing. It was yourself that brought up the issues with my test class which I am trying to resolve. Thanks anyway, I'll ry to resolve on my own.

Comment: Semantics. Your title suggests that it is an issue with your test class. If you add a system assert after querying for opportunities in your test then you will see that it really passes or not. Right now you posted your test like it is working but then saying the UI is not working. You still have not validated that your test actually works. So seems like you main issue is with your trigger and your test is irrelevant. I would suggest you reword your question and post a new one while deleting this one.

Comment: I obviously need to do some more learning as I haven't a clue what a sysem assert is. Thanks Eric

Answer (score 0):

At a minimum, your test class should be modified to look more like the following:

```
startTest();
insert c;

system.debug('account id = ' + c.Id);

c.Status = 'Activated';

update c;

endTest();

system.debug('status = ' + c.Status);

// system.assertEquals(c.Status,'Activated');
// once the debug statement is showing Activated, uncomment above statement
```

Comment: End of test amended to include but I get te below error
 Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '{' at line 31 column 12

Comment: Since I don't know what's on line 31, I can't say for certain, but it sounds like you may have a missing semi-colon on the line before it if there's a brace there or something along those lines. You may need to change the commented sections to use `/*` and `*/` if the problem is within a commented line.

Comment: It's the { after system.debug that's triggering the error

Comment: @CaptainHaZ - I updated his code. there was a { instead of (

Comment: @Eric, thanks. That happens when you write code on the fly. :)

Comment: This unit test is pointless. You may as well write `System.assertEquals('Activated','Activated');`, because that's effectively what you're doing. Check to see if the opportunity was created.

Comment: @sfddcfox You're spot on. I didn't look at his trigger code to see exactly what it did, instead, only his test class when I wrote that he needed to at least do the above. My point was to show the pattern, not to correct all the short-comings in his test class.